# pandas transpose data in excel to single column

Tags: python, json, excel, pandas, dataframe

So, for reasons that are unbeknownst to myself, my client has a lot of data stored in JSON-style format, but in Excel files. They are currently laid next to each other, but they want them stacked (not sure why, but I'm not in the business of telling people how to do their business.)

What the data looks like:

[image: before]

and what I want it to look like:

[image: after]

yes, I know this will not create a valid JSON file, but there's a lot to unpack here and it's not worth getting into. I'm just doing what I'm asked to do.

I've tried sending each column to a list and putting said list in a parent list eg: `[[col1],[col2]...]` but that spread the data across the columns, rather than sending it down a row into a single column. Thanks in advance, sorry if this made your brain hurt, it made mine hurt too.

EDIT:

I tried using the `stack()` function and, while it did yield one column of data, it did not have it the way I wanted. For it went across and down I was given:

```
{
{
{
{
"alpha":[
"alpha":[
"alpha":[
"alpha":[
{
{
{
...
```

Which isn't great, but I guess a step in the right direction.

Comment: Does it need to be carried out using `pandas`?

Comment: I suppose not, but it was the first option that sprang to mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using pandas

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("./input.xlsx",header=None)
df = df.T.stack()
df.to_excel("./output.xlsx", index=False, header=False)
```

**Explanation:**

pandas.dataframe.read_excel() loads the excel contents into a dataframe. Make sure to set header=None as your data doesn't have any header.

pandas.dataframe.stack() can do something similar to what you want. However it stacks in a different order. ( row1 row2 row3, etc). Hence, we first Transpose the data before stacking them.

Finally, pandas.dataframe.to_excel() exports the output back to an excel file. we are setting header and index to False so that it doesn't export some extra details that we do not need.

[input.xlsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7Ci1.png)

[output.xlsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9L3tm.png)

Comment: Ah! Good shout on the `.T` with `.stack()`. This worked well enough for me. Thanks a lot!